# Why will spinner (Bootstrap 5.x) not display?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get this spinner to display when the user clicks a form submit button.  Here's the HTML to include a `<div>` for the spinner:

```
<div class="pageloader">  
    <img src="../images/loader-large.gif" alt="Please wait..." />  
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the `pageloader` class:

```
.pageloader {
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.8 );
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.pageloader img {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px;
    margin-top: -32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

When the user clicks the submit button in the form, I call this code in my script:
 `$(".pageloader").fadeIn();`

I then make an AJAX call, and in the `always` block I have this code:
`$(".pageloader").fadeOut();`

Now, the form submission works.  When the submit button is clicked, the AJAX call fires, but the spinner never displays, and I get no error messages in the console.  Any clues here?  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using a Bootstrap spinner?

Comment: I tried that and couldn't figure it out either.  Thought maybe I'd have better luck with this.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.js` file and use `<div id="pageloader"></div>` instead of `class`.

```js
const select = (el, all = false) => {
  el = el.trim()
  if (all) {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
  } else {
    return document.querySelector(el)
  }
}
let pageloader = select('#pageloader');
if (pageloader) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    preloader.remove()
  });
}
```